# deriving the master public key and the btc address from seed phrase of electrum wallet

Tags: electrum, public-key, seed, xpub, hardened-derivation

I am searching for an **exact python code** that can take a *standard wallet* seed as input and output the the *root key* or *xpub master public key*.
I had tried several codes but none of them gave me the '**exact same**' xpub mpk as of the real electrum wallet. Can I get some help.

Comment: thanks to give me this website name but this might take some time to understand what all this site has to offer. I will answer the question my self I got any break through .Thanks again

Comment: iancoleman xpub doesn't match the electrum one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert an Electrum seed phrase to a BIP39 seed phrase, because in the process of deriving the master private keys, both algorithms use a different salt. This means, you cannot use Electrum seed phrases to generate BIP39-phrase addresses.

However, it **is** possible to derive Electrum addresses from Electrum seed phrases even outside Electrum. There is a short guide [here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5482172.msg63525507#msg63525507) even though it is for testnet, it also works for mainnet just by switching the coin type.

To quote it:

> 1. Download [bip39-standalone.html](https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39/releases).
> 2. Go to line 28611 and replace "return h == nh;" with "return true;".
> 3. Go to line 28639 and replace "mnemonic" with "electrum".
> 4. Open bip39-standalone.html in your browser and paste your seed phrase.
> 5. Select "Bitcoin - Testnet" from "Coin".
> 6. In "Derivation Path", select BIP141, P2WPKH and use: m/0'/0

Note: To get P2PKH address use the m/0 path, m/0'/0 is only for Electrum's segwit P2WPKH.

Comment: the answer is correct and i also found a working tool right next to what you mention here https://github.com/FarCanary/ElectrumSeedTester

Comment: actually its js code also i am unable to extract any python code from it or interpret how the html is actually calculating in short no progress made